# How to access data outside the onclick function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js

I need to access my component's data property (`id[]`) from within the `onClick` function of my Chart initialization object, but I get an `undefined` error when I try `id[position]`:

```
window.open("/#/user/history/detail/" + id[position], "_self");
```

My data property:

```js
data() {
  return {
    id: [1,2,3,4,5]
  };
}
```

and `onClick` function:

```js
mounted() {
  this._chart = new Chart({
    ...
    onClick: function(evt, array) {
      if (array.length != 0) {
        var position = array[0]._index;
        console.log(position);
        window.open("/#/user/history/detail/" + id[position], "_self"); //problem
      } else {
        console.log("You selected the background!");
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onClick: function(evt, array) { }`, `this` is the `Chart` instance. To bind the context to the Vue instance, use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this):

```
this._chart = new Chart({
  onClick: (evt, array) => {
    ...
    console.log(this.id[position])
  }
)
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sko36by9/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `this` when referring to a variable from your component's `data` and `props` attribute.

So instead of:

```
window.open("/#/user/history/detail/" + id[position], "_self");
```

Use:

```
window.open("/#/user/history/detail/" + this.id[position], "_self");
```

Comment: after I Do this I got 'undefined'

Comment: @JirakitPaitoonnaramit Can you create a codesandbox or a fiddle that shows how this issue is occuring? It would make it easier to debug and solve it faster.